# Running program in a loop for different parameters via console

Tags: c++

I have a simple question: I wrote a DDE-solver for my Bachelor-thesis to solve a differential equation system. Problem is: I need to run the program several times for different parameters. Since I dont want to have nested for loops, I thought of running the program via console with some kind of script which gives the parameter as an argument to the console. The idea is:

for par1=1; par1<10; par1++

```
run DDEsolver.cpp
```

The reason why I want to do it this way, is that I have so many different parameters, that it would be easier to just replace the parameter "par1" in the script and implement a line of code in the program who just reads the parameter out of the command line and overwrites the parameter in the code everytime it's running.

I hope you understand what I want, and I apologize for my bad english, I am not a native speaker.

Thanks for your help!

P.S.: I'm working on windows system.

Comment: So what is the question or problem? Have you not learnt how to read arguments passed to your C++ `main` function?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (for you) would be to prepare a text file with the parameters you wish to use. Write a function to load the text file and initialize your solver's parameters. Your main() might look something like this:

```
int usage();
void read_parameters_from_file( const std::string& filename );
void solve();
void print_results();

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  if (argc != 2) return usage();
  read_parameters_from_file( argv[1] );
  solve();
  print_results();
}
```

Thereafter you only need the parameter files in a directory, and you can run each solver with a simple batch file:

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*.txt) do DDEsolver.exe %%F
```

That’s it!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will definitely try that!